# How can I have admin language English and frontend language another?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I would like to create a site to display the frontend of the site in one language and still keep the backend in English (or another language).

Is there a module like "**[Administration Language"](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_language)** or any configuration for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First go to Administration - Configuration - Regional and language - Languages - Detection and selection tab and make sure to have “Account administration pages“ enabled.

Then go to People and edit your user. Go down to the Language settings section. You should now see a Administration pages language dropdown. Select and save.

Comment: I couldn't find this options,  please add imgs

Comment: With these settings in D8 I am not able to see the different languages when editing a page. They are all in the same language as selected from the default admin language dropdown in the user settings ... why?

Comment: Have same problem @Lance it's a bug check out this post - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2189267

Answer (score 4):

> This module has been included with Drupal 8 core. Refer to this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2623206) for more information.

That information is shown in the blue box on the page that you linked to.

The linked page has also information on how to configure this in Drupal 8.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and attention, I do that setting but I Fond this problem:  [Administration Pages language Always English and admin menu Always in left side?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205878/administration-pages-language-always-english-and-admin-menu-always-in-left-side).    Thank you for any help again.

Comment: Once enabled it seems that "Site language" is used as fallback. Why does the "Account administration pages" also affect the language of the frontend? "Follow the user's language preference" is not enabled so I'd expect it to be limited to administration pages.